# Soundproof Garage Ceiling

Tags: drywall, ceiling, garage, joists

I’m building a soundproof room in a garage for a friend, after having done something similar for myself, but am not sure about the ceiling. I was planning to use two layers of acoustic plasterboard (roughly 40kg per 2.4x1.2m), with rock wool in between the joists. The joists in the garage look like this:

[image: joists]

Would that be too much mass for the joists, or would it be okay?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Without more info, the answer is going to be "it depends"; could you add a diagram, with the dimensions of the ceiling area to be soundproofed? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/146400/46271.  Good related info